# How long before expiration can you renew a US Passport?

Tags: usa, legal, passports

My US passport expires in just over a year but I've only got one empty page left in it and I've already had extra pages added once.

I'm going to be in the US for a short while and am considering renewing my passport while I'm there.

Am I able to renew a passport that has more than one year of validity left on it so that I can get a new one with more pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your passport qualifies to [add more pages](http://travel.state.gov/passport/correcting/add/add_850.html) if you prefer.  It costs a little less in the short run, but you will have to mail your passport with the application form.

Although I was not able to find any info specifically on [the State Dept website](http://travel.state.gov/passport/renew/renew_833.html) about this topic, any restrictions on how early you can renew are conspicuously absent.

Information on various US embassy pages from other countries also suggests that you can renew at any time:

From http://brazil.usembassy.gov/service/frequently-asked-questions.html:

> #### How soon should I renew my passport before it expires?
>
> You may apply to renew your U.S. passport at any time.

From: http://london.usembassy.gov/cons_new/faqs/faq_passports.html:

> #### How soon should I renew my passport before it expires?
>
> You may [renew your passport](http://london.usembassy.gov/cons_new/acs/passports/renindex.html) at any time before or after it expires.

Comment: Since it costs $82 for additional pages and $110 per renewal, additional pages are penny wise, pound foolish.  In addition, the State Department will only add additional pages once per passport.  Once your additional pages are filled, you must renew.

Comment: From what I read, they'll add pages twice. I've already done it once, but since I've only got a year left of validity I probably won't use all the pages within the year and will have to renew anyways.

Answer (score 4):

There is no restriction on how early you renew your passport - it costs them just the same since you're paying for it anyway - it just doesn't make sense to, obviously, if you have lots of pages.  However in your case you may indeed want to.

From the Bureau of Consular Affairs: [How to Renew Your US Passport](http://travel.state.gov/passport/renew/renew_833.html)

And if you wish to find your closest location to do so, if you're not going to be mailing it in:

[Passport Acceptance Facility Search Page](http://iafdb.travel.state.gov/)